# is this a dynamic library linker issue

Tags: c, linux, dynamic, linker, libraries

I have some very simple C code I was trying to compile and link to try to understand how static and dynamic libraries work and also BFDs.  The code snippet is below and my question beneath it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bfd.h"

unsigned int number_of_sections(bfd *abfd)
{
  return bfd_count_sections(abfd);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  bfd *ibfd = NULL;
  unsigned int numSections = 0;

  if (argc < 2)
    {
      printf("Argc < 2\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  else
    {
      bfd_init();
      printf("filename = %s\n", argv[1]);
      ibfd = bfd_openr(argv[1], NULL);
      numSections = number_of_sections(ibfd);
      printf("num sections = %d\n", numSections);
    }
  return 1;
}
```

The code to compile and link it is below, along with the error:

```
make -f makefile
gcc -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/bin -g -Wall -I. -I/usr/include -o getsections ./getsections.c -lbfd -liberty -lz 
./libbfd.a(plugin.o): In function `try_load_plugin':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.23.1/build-dir/bfd/../../bfd/plugin.c:170: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.23.1/build-dir/bfd/../../bfd/plugin.c:177: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.23.1/build-dir/bfd/../../bfd/plugin.c:173:     undefined reference to `dlerror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build] Error 1

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Thu Feb 27 16:26:12
```

I searched and searched and could not find the answer to what is most likely a very simple question, and I apologize in advance for my ignorance!

Comment: Add the linker flag `-ldl`?

Comment: Aren't you missing `#include <dlfcn.h>`?

Comment: @Asblarf You don't have to include the header file for functions that you only call indirectly through another library. As another example, `fopen` calls `open` but you don't need to include `unistd.h` to call `fopen`. That seems to be the same case here with the dl* calls coming from bfd.

Answer (score 3):

Add `-ldl` after `-lbfd` to tell the linker where to find the missing functions.

Comment: Thank you all for responding!  This was the problem.